# Why am I getting an error that says "Listview cannot be converted into integer".?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to find the highest number in a list of entered value using a do while loop, but I get an error when I try to convert the list from a listview into an integer. Any help would be appreciated, and while I'm not new to programming, I am fairly new to the syntax of vb, sorry.

```
    listofgrades = listpgrades.Items.Count
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim lstSize As Integer = listpgrades.Items.Count
    Dim max As Integer = CInt(listpgrades.Items(0))

    Do While (i < lstSize - 1)
        If CInt(listpgrades.Items(i)) < max Then
            max = CInt((listpgrades.Items(i))

        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: Because you didnt specify what about `.Item(i)` you wanted to use. in VB.NET, there is no implicit conversion... no "default properties" like you are apparently used to in VBA. Did you want the `.Value` of the item?

Comment: thank you, and yes I want the value, so would I say .Item(i. ____)?

Comment: Think.  `listpgrades.Items(i)` is a `ListViewItem`; an object like any other.  How do you usually get a property value from an object?  You obviously already know because you're already doing it multiple times in that code.  @braX even showed you in their comment. That said, there is no `Value` property so think about what property it actually is that you want.

Comment: thanks, I see what I need to do, I just really wasn't thinking before.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim lstSize As Integer = listpgrades.Items.Count
        Dim max As Integer = CInt(listpgrades.Items(0).Text)

        Do While (i < lstSize)
            If Regex.IsMatch(listpgrades.Items(i).Text, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then
                If CInt(listpgrades.Items(i).Text) > max Then
                    max = CInt(listpgrades.Items(i).Text)
                End If
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
```

I've added a control in my code: if the value is a number then check if is greater than max variable. Try this! :)

NB

'CInt(listpgrades.Items(i)) < max' is not correct!

----> 'CInt(listpgrades.Items(i)) > max '

I've also corrected the 'Do While (i < lstSize - 1)' bcs it will not control the last value

Comment: `listpgrades.Items(i).Text.ToString()` is useless code.. `.Text` is a string already so there's no point in calling `.ToStriong()` on something that is already a string. `listpgrades.Items(i).Text` is sufficient in this case.